# I am having trouble uploading bootstrap via the terminal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am not importing bootstrap correctly and i can not figure out why.

I ran npm save bootstrap and imported the file to my index.js File and the 
 per docs.And styling still wont apply.

Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
ReactDOM.render(

    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>,

  document.getElementById("root")
);


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

NavBar.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from "../logo.svg";

export default class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm  bg-primary navbar-dark px-sm-5">
          {/* 
  https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/1243689/call_phone_icon
  Creative Commons (Attribution 3.0 Unported);
  https://www.iconfinder.com/Makoto_msk */}
          <Link to="/">
            <img 
            src={logo} 
            alt="store" 
            className="navbar-brand"/>
          </Link>

          <ul className=" navbar-nav align-items-center">
            <li className="nav-item ml-5">
            <Link to="/" className="nav-link">
            Products
            </Link>
            </li> 
          </ul>
        </nav>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: `npm install bootstrap`

Comment: I ran this and imported it into my index.js file already. I read the doc

Comment: Ok, you have `npm save bootstrap` in your post so wanted to make sure. If your only intention is to include bootstrap CSS in your code then you can go to `public/index.html` and  add this code in head tag over there directly `<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: This is not working for instance this is the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/0c9iz Take off the bootstrap dependency and that is how it looks

Comment: Right, over there you are adding it as an external dependency which is added in head tag of your resulting HTML. If you inspect over rendered HTML in codesandbox you will see that its in the head tag. That's what I'm suggesting that you do for your react app. Go to public/index.html file and then edit that file directly to include bootstrap in it.

Comment: I did and it is still not working I added the cdn to bootstrap in the head of my index file like I would a normal site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193937/discussion-between-rikin-and-codingoni).